# Unintuitive process run time

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, kernel

I measured the running time of a process on Ubuntu. The process has two threads, the main process thread and a child thread that is killed and re-spawned a lot of times by the main thread. It looks something like this:

```
main_thread
{
   timer=0;
   loop(N)
   {
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start)

     spwan_new_thread();
     do_main_thread_work();
     join_child_thread()

     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end)
     time+=end-start
   }

   print time/N
}

new_tread()
{
   do_child_thread_work();
   return;
}
```

The run time results say that this process runs a bit faster on two cores than on 3 cores. I have to mention that I use the same system, I just disable or enable a core.

The two core configuration is 0.4 ms faster then 3 core configuration and I did 100 executions on each configuration to make sure it's not just luck.

Why would this happen? (kernel scheduler?)

**EDIT**

Loop avg execution time on 2 cores: 5.92587 ms
Loop avg execution time on 3 cores: 6.36628 ms

I disable cores by using files like /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online

Comment: Many reasons are possible, but you didn't give enough info for more than a wild guess at which applies.  How big a fraction is .4 ms?  What kind of activity does the child thread do?  What CPU?  How did you disable a core? etc.?  Anyway, my wild guess is cache loading.  By switching a tiny operation from one core to another, you are moving data through main memory that could otherwise have stayed in cache.

Comment: The pseudo code isn't very expressive. You seem to join the single thread you create in the loop before you create a new one --  are you sure you have any parallelism (beyond a single child thread vs. the main thread) at all? My guess is that more cores than parallel threads slow down a system due to book keeping/sync overhead. 0.4ms is nothing anyway.

Comment: I'm not interested in optimizations of the code. 0.4 ms is something if the total process time is 6 ms. Both threads do similar work(image processing) and the data is obtained using the same input each time.

Comment: You are right, it's about 8% or so. But as I said, what makes you think that more cores *that you don't use* accelerate anything? It's even possible that a modern CPU can clock fewer cores higher because there's a lower thermal load...

Comment: Your question is vague as someone has already mentioned.  But here is a ***[conversation](http://superuser.com/questions/2489/cpu-cores-the-more-the-better)*** that may answer your concern.  Do you see any trend in durations if you let it run longer? Say for several minutes instead of several seconds?

Comment: @PeterSchneider I use this CPU http://ark.intel.com/products/78475/Intel-Atom-Processor-E3845-2M-Cache-1_91-GHz

It has a power governor which may lower the frequency of some cores

Comment: @ryyker I explained the measurements wrong. The time I was talking about is an average time for one loop iteration. The loop runs 2000 times and I did an average over obtained times. Also I did this experiment 100 times for each configuration and the measurements are consistent.

Comment: that sample size is pretty small (100) considering that the runtime of each thread is only 5.9ms...you should run your test much longer than that (larger sample and thread runtime). -- EDIT: Just read the above comment. nvm. should stil not average them though, and just plot teh distribution of times.

Comment: How do you measure? Please show your exact commands or function calls.

Comment: @RollenD'Souza 5.9 ms is the run time of one iteration of the loop and loop executes 2000 times per experiment.

Comment: @n.m. I use clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &var) at the beginning and end of the loop

Comment: I edit the post and added details about time measurement.

Comment: You are measuring wall time. Try CPU time (CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID). Perhaps the scheduler gives your program fewer slices with 3 cores, or another process that runs on the third core periodically steals the CPU, or something.

Comment: I would say that CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID should be the same on both configurations since I use the same input and the number of instructions executed is roughly  the same. Mostly I'm interested in overall performance (maybe it's kind of wrong because it includes kernel time too)

Comment: Wall time is imo a legit criteria. It's actually the only thing users are interested in ;-). Your system's overall performance seems to decrease somewhat when you add a core. The [data sheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/atom-e3800-family-datasheet.pdf) seems to indicate that this atom has thermal throttling, so that may be one reason, or some kernel/memory overhead related to managing a third core.

Comment: Since you added some hardware info, I'll adjust my earlier guess.  The slow down is **NOT** as I guessed earlier moving data through main memory that otherwise could have stayed in cache.  But for a narrow range of code/data size you might get the same effect because (by enabling 3 cores and only using 2 at a time) you are moving data through L2 cache that could have stayed in L1 cache.

Comment: There are a lot of variables that could be affecting. For example OS could be changing the dispatcher algorithm depending on how much cores your processor has, or maybe it changes the time slices it gives to each process. Maybe neither and the processes running are too short so dispatcher is called more often on more cores, generating more overhead
Or maybe shared cache memory fills faster on 3 cores resulting in need to move data to next cache level or RAM

Comment: The datasheet for that processor shows that there are two L2 caches for the 4 cores, each L2 is shared by 2 cores. So exactly which core(s) you're disabling could be quite relevant. If the two threads are sharing data, it might be quite advantageous to be sharing the L2 (to avoid cache invalidation/transfers). OTOH, if the 2 threads use totally different sets of data, it might be quite advantageous *not* to share the L2 (to avoid unnecessary cache evictions).

Comment: Hmmm ... I think you may have a point about L2 shared cache. Since I don't know which cores share the L2 and I also don't know on which core will the new thread be executed or if the OS scheduler takes into account the shared cache, it is kind of hard to know if it's an advantage or not that I have shared cache between 2 cores.

Comment: @PeterSchneider It's actually the only thing *single-tasking PC* users are interested in. Other people run many different jobs at any given time, or (gasp) pay for cycles in the cloud

Comment: In my experience, such behavior is mostly due to 2 cores running at a higher clock rate than 3 cores. Are you setting CPU governor in performance mode?